# Readability API - Parsing Specific Sub category of RSS Feed using JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've parsed the following RSS (http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rss.cms) in this way-

My code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>News Parser</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var url1 = "https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=";
var testurl = "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rss.cms";
var urltoken = "&token=18ba7d424a0d65facdaea8defa356bc3e430f8ce";
var finalurl = url1 + testurl + urltoken; 
console.debug(finalurl)

$(function()
 {
   $.ajax(
    {        
             url:finalurl,
             dataType: "json",
             contentType:"application/json",
             success: function (data)
               {
                     console.log(data);
                     console.log(data.content);
                     //console.error(JSON.parse(data.content));
                     $("body").empty().append(data.content);
               },
               error:function(d)
                {
                     console.log(d);
                }
              });   
 });
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
  p
  {
    color: green;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm getting the content of RSS Feed like this -

[image]

**Now i want to parse Specific Sub- Category of RSS Feeds like SPort, Technology etc. How could i do, If i m passing the specific url of the sub category, which is **http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533921/index.rss, http://www.thehindu.com/sport/?service=rss**,

I m getting blank window.

Please suggest me **how could i parse specific Sub Category of RSS Feeds**?

Comment: @Omar you have any idea, how could i resolve it..

Comment: can you post a sample of returned JSON?

Comment: @Omar i've added image in my question, have a look

Comment: @Omar the above image content is the json of my code...

Comment: I've checked the website, RSS feeds don't return any data.

Comment: @Omar use this rss feed in my code http://www.thehindu.com/sport/?service=rss ... i want to parse this, it is the sub category of RSS

Comment: this returns XML. it's difficult to test it due to "_No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'_" error.

Comment: @Omar i have updated working token in my question, use it

Comment: @Omar i tried but with the help of readability api... it is not getting parsed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sub Category of RSS Feeds

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Car</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">           
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Page 1 -->
    <div data-role="page" id="firstPage" >
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Rss Feed</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="content">

        </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /Page End -->
    </body>
</html>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533921/index.rss',
    dataType:'xml',
    type:'GET',
    success:function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();                 
            var link = $(this).find("link").text();
            var description = $(this).find("description").text();
            var pubDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();

            $("#content").append('<div><p><a href="'+link+'">'+title+'</a><p><p>'+pubDate+'<p><p>'+description+'<p><div>');                  
         });
    },
    error:function() {
        alert("Feed error..!");
    }
});   


$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.thehindu.com/sport/?service=rss',
    dataType:'xml',
    type:'GET',
    success:function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();  
            var category = $(this).find("category").text();               
            var link = $(this).find("link").text();
            var description = $(this).find("description").text();
            var pubDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();                
            $("#content").append('<div><p><a href="'+link+'">'+title+'</a><p><p>'+pubDate+'<p><p>'+description+'<p><div><p>Category: '+category+'<p><div>');                  
         });
    },
    error:function() {
        alert("Feed error..!");
    }
});
```